# Vue 3 components not working [Vue warn]: Invalid VNode type: undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I recently upgraded to VueJS 3 and am using async components, but when importing them they do not work as they should. I have tried to Google fixes for this but nothing worked.

This is my app JS file (ps if anyone knows a better way to load components better (each basically in their own "app", let me know! :wink:)):

```js
import { createApp, defineAsyncComponent } from 'vue';
import '../sass/app.scss';

const app = createApp({});

app.component('test', () => defineAsyncComponent(() => import(/* webpackChunkName: "components/Test" */ './components/Test'))).mount('#test-v');
```

Comment: Why is it `() => defineAsyncComponent` and not `defineAsyncComponent`?

Comment: Because I am high on crack thank you that fixed it LOL.